# Two RFID RC522 communicate with each other using Arduino UNOs

Tags: arduino, nfc, rfid, master-slave, smartcard-reader

I am trying to make two independent Arduino UNO communicate with each other by using two RFID RC522. One should act as master and the second one as a slave:
[image]

How can I make one RC522 as master and the second as slave?

Answer (score 3):

The MFRC522 is a pure reader IC and only implements the (active) reader part for  ISO/IEC 14443 Type A. It neither supports operating as the card side for ISO/IEC 14443 Type A nor does it support operating in NFC peer-to-peer mode.

Consequently, you can't have two MFRC522 communicate with each other.